# Rails - Returning a string value in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello StackOverflow :) ,
I have a question about a Collection_Select in a form.

First, the collection select is a filter in a Searchform and the display of the select is working, the problem is the value passed to the request.

Before I had a text_field_tag which was working fine:

```
  <% text_field_tag :book_name, params[:book_name], placeholder: 'Book' %> #Text field Works
```

> Return the param in the console  `"Book_name"=>"Harry Potter"`

Second choice with the collection Select :

```
 <%game = Book.find_by name: params[:book_name] %>
 <% collection_select(:book, :book_name, Book.all, :id, :name, {selected: book.try(:id)}, prompt: true) %>
```

> Return this in the console : `"book"=>{"book_name"=>"2"}` and I would
>   like to return just the same as above

```
"book_name" => "Name"
```

Here is the Search controller, maybe should I change this one ?

```
def search
    if params[:book_name].present?
      @searchs = User.joins(:books).where(books: {name: params[:books_name]}).near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10)

     elsif params[:city].present?
        @searchs = User.near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10).where("id != ?", current_user.id)

    else
      @searchs = User.none
```

I hope someone could help me on that. I tried many different ways but nothing worked ! Many Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do both things. 
If you prefer to pass the book name you should use

```
<% f.collection_select(:book, :book_name, Book.all, :name, :name, your_options = {}, your_html_options = {} %>
```

(note the double `:name`, the first one is for the option *value* and the second one is for the option *text*)

But, let me say, performing a search by name is not the best practice. querying by string is extremely slower than using an id. So, if I were you, I'll keep the `collection_select` as is and I'll change the search using the id like this:

```
      @searchs = User.joins(:books).where(books: {id: params[:books_id]}).near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10)
```

or even

```
@searchs = User.joins(:books).where('book_id = ?', params[:book_id]).near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10)
```

If you have more doubts, take a look the `collection_select` [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I prefer to use IDs too , much better for the search. Perfect answer, I will try this and keep you posted ;)

Comment: Maybe you could help me on this , I still have the param like this when I submit the search '"book"=>{"book_name"=>"2"}', with the double arrow, do you know a way to change this to 'book_name => 2' , and skip the first arrow ? Or do I have to change something in the Search controller  ? I am sorry I am a bit new to rails

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? (are you using string_parameters in your controller?) 
Anyway.. I'm not understanding very well your question.. do you mean doing `params[:book]` you get `{"book_name"=>"2"}` ?

Comment: The search controller is working with this param, I tested it with the Text_field_tag : '"Book_name => "HarryPotter" ' and when I query with the collection select i got the param in my console embeded in another param,  like this ' Book => {'Book_name' => "HarryPotter"} ' . So the search is not expecting this kind of parameters, i just need the 'Book_name => ' Name' , not the book => bookname => "harry". I am using 4.2 rails. Thanks for your consideration :)

Comment: AHH! Maybe, I've understood. If you inspect the generated html code you see something like `<select name="book[book_name]"` right? That generates the params as you said. The solution is extract the part you need _before_ performing the search. For example using a `before_filter` . (take a look to strong_parameters!) Alternatively you can change your controller like this `@searchs = User.joins(:books).where('book_id = ?', params[:book][:book_name]). ... etc`

Comment: Exactly !! thanks Jonnyjava !! I will try this. Many thanks again

Comment: Try this in your console `hash = {"book"=>{"book_name"=>"harry"}}` and after do `hash['book']['book_name']` that's it!

Comment: that's working perfectly in the console , so i just need to change the search controller by adding the [:book] param , I will try right now

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `:id`

```
<% collection_select(:book, :book_name, Book.all, :id, :name, {selected: book.try(:id)}, prompt: true) %>
```

This way you're returning ':name'

```
<% collection_select(:book, :book_name, Book.all, :name, :name, {selected: Book.find_by_name(:name)}, prompt: true) %>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , just changed the selected with a capital for 'Game.find_by_name'. Thanks Steve

Comment: No probs, Martin.... good catch about the "Game" (or "Book") being capitalized. I've updated the answer.